# dates from db are not in the right format for parsing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to load data from the db but I am getting a date format error:
[image]

Here is the data in the db:
[image]

Here is the code. Every date field has the same code.

```
 final String? contractDate = trxnSnapshot.data()?['contractDate'];
        if (contractDate != null && contractDate != "") {
          _dt = DateTime.parse(contractDate);
          contractDateController.text =
              DateFormat('EE,  MM-dd-yyyy').format(_dt) ?? "";
        } else {
          contractDateController.text = "";
        }
```

I'm not seeing what is wrong with this date I have in the database. I am getting the error when I am trying to parse the date.

Comment: I think my problem is I am storing everything as String but I am trying to parse like they are datetime. Is this correct?

Comment: Usually databases have some sort of internal date format, and a query tool (like a command line interface, or GUI manager) will have a default format for displaying it, but that is not related to what you get back from a database query (some, like sqlite, don't, and use some other type instead). Depending on the database, you could retrieve the column value as a `DateTime`, or maybe explicitly format the result in your query to match the format you want.

Comment: If `contractDate` is a `String` of the form `'Fri, 11-10-2023'`, then you should be using `DateFormat('EE, MM-dd-yyyy').parse(contractDate)` instead of using `DateTime.parse`.  However, it's really unclear why you're parsing it at all since your code is trying to display it in that same format.  The whole thing could be just `contractDateController.text = contractDate ?? '';`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had a bit of a brain fart on this one.

Answer (score 0):

contractDate sees the date model as a string. You need to turn it into history first.

```
  final String? contractDate = trxnSnapshot.data()?['contractDate'];
      if (contractDate != null && contractDate != "") {
       String dateFormat = 'E,dd-MM-yyyy';
       DateFormat format = DateFormat(dateFormat);
       _dt = format.parse(contractDate);
       contractDateController.text =
          DateFormat('EE,  MM-dd-yyyy').format(_dt) ?? "";
    } else {
      contractDateController.text = "";
    }
```